# SQL Server Full Text Index query

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to build a query based on a full text index.

Basically i'm searching for any emails contains the phrase "dynamics crm", I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EmailMessages 
WHERE 
CONTAINS(toaddresses, 'myaddress') 
AND CONTAINS(RawMessage,'dynamics crm')
```

That gives: "Syntax error near 'crm' in the full-text search condition 'dynamics crm'."

Do I need to use %% as in a LIKE query? Or something else?

Thanks

Comment: select * from.... where ... like '%dynamics crm%'

Comment: I thought you couldn't use LIKE on a full text index?

Comment: You can see the basics here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to wrap the phrase in double quotes:

```
CONTAINS(RawMessage, '"dynamics crm"')
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx